Is the virtual DOM in VueJS redundant?
Can anyone tell me if VueJS has fine-grained reactivity, similar to signals that use a sub-push mechanism to update directly on the actual DOM? If so, does that make the virtual DOM redundant?
I want to understand more about fine-grained reactivity in VueJS. Can it update directly on the actual DOM? If so, what is the purpose of the virtual DOM when it no longer needs to compare the previous version to find changes and update the actual DOM?

Making changes to the DOM is very slow and heavy. Virtual DOM makes it faster and easier by adopting a state model that will streamline that part so that you can focus on the things that matter. Also yes, fine-grained reactivity is important so that if something changes, the changes are reflected in the 25 places using that variable rather than you doing it by yourself. VueJS got this far before the "signals" were even a thing by using Signals. Check the documentation for more: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html TLDR: let Vue focus on the DOM so that you can build stuff.

@kissu The interesting part in the docs is new vapor mode which is supposed to address this
